# pandas pd.DataFrame.diff(axis=1) NotImplementationError

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that generates from pd.pivot_table with columns having datetime.

I want to calculate the time difference along columns. So I used `df.diff(axis=1)`. I got `NotImplementedError`.

I came across this pull request in Github: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/19773

I guess the problem has been solved? Why I still get NonImplementedError?

Data Sample:
[image]
Please ignore the "Text". Typo.

Comment: What version of pandas are you running? Maybe just need to upgrade?

Comment: @ChrisA I use 1.0.1

Comment: Hmmm, I'm using the same. Working for me with datetime types. What about versions for `numpy` and `python-dateutil` ?

Comment: @ChrisA numpy 1.18.1 python-dateutil 2.8.1

Comment: I also have some NaT value in the columns. Would that affect?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce with `NaT` - appears to work ok for me

Comment: df.dtypes shows all columns is `datetime64[ns, UTC]`

Comment: @ChrisA I got it works by removing the timezone: `data['date'] = data['date'].dt.tz_convert(None)`

Comment: Good find! You should add as an answer, could be useful for others.

Comment: I also got 88424 days when the previous column is NaT. Any hints?

Comment: In the context of your data, does it make sense to forward fill to deal with `NaT` ? : `df.ffill(axis=1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to remove the timezone in `datetime64[ns, UTC]` columns. It works!

`data['date'] = data['date'].dt.tz_convert(None)`

Comment: gosh, i appreciate the ability to work with timezones, but they really screw up all the formatting. i wish the default would have stayed at not having them. suddenly, CSV readings produce different outputs... :(