# Pandas diff-function: NotImplementedError

Tags: pandas, azure, azure-dsvm

When I use the diff function in my snippet:

```
for customer_id, cus in tqdm(df.groupby(['customer_ID'])):
        # Get differences
        diff_df1 = cus[num_features].diff(1, axis = 0).iloc[[-1]].values.astype(np.float32)
```

I get:

```
NotImplementedError
```

The exact same code did run without any error before (on Colab), whereas now I'm using an Azure DSVM via JupyterHub and I get this error.

I already found this
[pandas pd.DataFrame.diff(axis=1) NotImplementationError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60596523/pandas-pd-dataframe-diffaxis-1-notimplementationerror)
but the solution doesnt work for me as I dont have any Date types. Also I did upgrade pandas but it didnt change anything.

**EDIT:** 
I have found that the error occurs when the datatype is 'int16' or 'int8'. Converting the dtypes to 'int64' solves it.
However I leave the question open in case someone can explain it or show a solution that works with int8/int16.

Comment: What is `num_features`?

Comment: any changes in the data? for example `num_features` or `customer_ID`?

Comment: @BeRT2me a list with column names (numerical columns), please see my Edit

Comment: @perpetualstudent No, please see Edit

Comment: oh i see, it could be due to the data type difference between python native int type and the numpy int types